# Logparser: Looping filter multiple list and output to multiple files using list value as file name

Tags: sql, batch-file, logparser

I'm stuck on a dead end with this logparser dilemma. so there's no where else to go but here.

## Batch file (*disktrend.bat*)

```
@echo off    
pushd "Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (d:logs\serverdrives.txt) do @logparser -i:tsv file:D:\logs\disktrend.sql?sd=%%A -o:chart -charttype:line > D:\logs\%%B.gif
```

## SQL file (*disktrend.sql*)

```
SELECT date,pfree using to_int(sub(to_real(100),to_real(replace_chr(free,'%','')))) as pfree,replace_chr(strcat(server,drive),':','') AS serverdrive from d:\logs\compiled\*.log where serverdrive =%sd%
```

## List file (*serverdrives.txt*)

```
'SERV06F',SERV06F  
'SERV00F',SERV00F
```

## Log file sample content (**.log*)

```
Date    Server  Drive   Free    Free Space  Total
20120914    SERV06      F:  79.55%  27619.02MB  34719.82MB
20120914    SERV00      F:  99.73%  34630.37MB  34723.81MB
```

When I run the batch script, I get below error:

## Error

```
Invalid output filename ""   
Invalid output filename ""
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: +1; Refreshingly well constructed question from a new user. Wish I could help, but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @dbenham. i got it already :)

Answer (score 1):

while eating dinner an answer suddenly popped on me.
I edited the Batch and SQL files.
See below.

## Batch file (*disktrend.bat*)

```
@echo off    
pushd "Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%A in (d:logs\serverdrives.txt) do @logparser -i:tsv file:D:\logs\disktrend.sql?sd=%%A+filen=%%B -o:chart -charttype:smoothline -q:off -stats:off
```

## SQL file (*disktrend.sql*)

```
SELECT to_string(date),pfree using to_int(sub(to_real(100),to_real(replace_chr(free,'%','')))) as pfree,replace_chr(strcat(server,drive),':','') AS serverdrive into d:\logs\%filen%.gif from d:\logs\compiled\*.log where serverdrive =%sd%
```